# What was the earliest piece of debris to survive reentry?

Tags: reentry, history, debris

Most orbital debris eventually re-enters the atmosphere. The vast majority of this burns up on re-entry, and only a small proportion of what's left lands on the surface.

Of that small proportion, the majority will land in the ocean (there is a lot of ocean!), and a fair chunk of the rest is probably never found, or just never identified. Nonetheless, every year or two something is turned up, and occasionally it's [very dramatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab#Re-entry).

When was the *first* time an object was found and identified as re-entering debris? I've been able to find a reference to a probable case in 1964 - Cosmos 50, which apparently had debris recovered in Malawi, discussed [on p. 30 here](http://orbitaldebris.jsc.nasa.gov/library/satellitefraghistory/13theditionofbreakupbook.pdf) - but nothing as yet from earlier. There were a number of cases as early as 1960 when debris from sub-orbital second stages were found in [unusual places](https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1961-63v25/d360), but that's not quite the same question...

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 5):

According [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reentering_space_debris), the earliest space debris that survived re-entry, were pieces and components from [Apollo SA-6 CSM BP-13 called AS-101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS-101_(spacecraft)) which was a testing spacecraft completing 54 orbits before re-entering in atmosphere and crashing in east of Kanton Island in the Pacific Ocean on June 1, 1964. These space debris are listed as the earliest to survive re-entry in atmosphere but i guess that were not recovered.

The re-entry date of Cosmos 50 was later on November 5, 1964 according the source you have found.

Comment: But did it actually reach the surface of the earth? I can't find any supporting information there. Possibly the writer of that sentence in Wikipedia just *assumes* some of it did.

Comment: I saw that list, but (while a bit vaguely worded) it seems to just be listing the largest objects to reenter - no indication that pieces were actually found. Hmm.